# IP Address Is A Guid-Like String

Tags: ip

When I get my IP address from Google, in most cases, it's a number like NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN (sometimes fewer than 3 Ns).  It always is in that format.  I noticed on this new wifi that my IP address is a completely different format according to Google (and `ipconfig`).  It's formatted like the below (different numbers and letters):

Eight numbers, four on each side of a colon:

```
2700:5400:
```

Then five other colons, separated in four sets each separated by numbers and letters:

```
3i44:4n2n (and more)
```

In total, the format is like:

```
NNNN:NNNN:NlNlNl:NlNlNl:NlNlNl:NlNlNl:NlNlNl:NlNlNl
```

Where `Nl` represents either a letter or number

What does it mean when an IP is configured this way?  In searching, I haven't found anyone posting an IP like this.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, that's an IPv6 address. And this is not a security question...

Comment: Recommended reading: [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4), [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6), [What questions can I ask about here?](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The stackexchange website where this question would belong to thematically would be https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ but this question is so basic it would likely get quite a negative response there.

Comment: @Philipp: I think that a better suggestion for such question would be [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). From non IPv6 aware end-users, I can understand that IPv6 addresses may look strange ;) ! But this is clearly a question related to home and not corporate networking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a security question.

The IP address you're getting from google, with the periods, [is based on  IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4). The "other one with the colons" [is based on IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6).

Please read up on them. Hope that helps you.